# How to get DATETIME and store to time_t using MySQL Connector/C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11, datetime

I'm using MySQL Connector/C++ as library to get result from MySQL database. I'm using C++11 standard. I want to get a `DATETIME` field (named *jointime*) from database and store it as `time_t` variable in follow:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    auto driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    auto con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "password");
    con->setSchema("mydb");
    auto stmt = con->createStatement();

    auto res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * from users;");
    while (res->next()) {
        string username = res->getString("username");
        time_t jt ; // res->get???
        ...
    }
    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete con;
}
```

How should I get *jointime* and assign it to `time_t jt`?

There isn't `getDateTime()` or relative method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL Connector/C++ returns `DATATIME` as `string`. The output format is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` so you need to write following function to convert this string to `time_t`:

```
time_t String2time_t(const string& strDateTime){
    tm t;
    strptime(strDateTime.c_str(), "%F %T", &t);
    return mktime(&t); 
}
```

Now use this line to get `DATETIME` and save it in a `time_t`:

```
time_t jt =  String2time_t((string)res->getString("jointime"));
```

Note that the output of `getString` is `SQLstring` not `std::string` so you need convert it to `std::string` before passing to the written function.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
Time var = new Time();
jt = var.time();
```

Comment: @ThomasSmyth tanks, I'm new and I wrote it in a block but it was published in that way.

Comment: I want to read the datetime from database which is accessible from `res` object. You havn't used this object ever!